# C# System.Timers.Timer - Please, how do I make it stop?

Tags: c#, timer

I've got a `Timer` that's doing a 60 second countdown.  When the ticks hit 60 seconds, it stops and disposes - no problem (I think).  This is run in the context of a `WebApi` service.  I need to be able to cancel the countdown from a UI, so I've exposed a method to handle this.  Since the controller is transient (thanks Luaan) and, as Daniel points out, the app pool is not predictable, I need a way to send a "cancellable" countdown to clients.  Ideas anyone?

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult CancelCountdown()
{
    // DOES NOTHING BECAUSE THERE'S A NEW INSTANCE OF THE CONTROLLER
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Dispose();
    return Ok();
}

private void StartCountdown()
{           
    // MAY BE A BAD SOLUTION BECAUSE THE APP POOL MAY RECYCLE
    timer.Interval = _timeIntervalInMilliseconds;
    timer.Elapsed += BroadcastToClients;
    timer.Start();
}

private void BroadcastToClients(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _elapsed += 1;
    if (_elapsed == _duration)//_duration is 60
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
        return;
    }                
    _messageHub.Clients.All.shutdown(_elapsed);
}
```

Comment: Unless you explicitly change that, each request is isolated. So you're probably creating a new `Timer` every time you make a request - stopping that timer doesn't affect any of the timers created previously.

Comment: not a good idea to make the timer a member of a controller.

Comment: @Luaan...of course!  You're right and it's obvious.

Comment: @DanielA.White...@Luaan is right and if not in the controller, then where?

Comment: you likely need something more durable bc the app pool can go away without warning. perhaps you can send the end time as a date to the clients and they calculate the time left themselves.

Comment: @DanielA.White...good idea.  I'm going to re-phrase the question because it's misleading now.

Comment: Won't caching timer object in HttpContext.Current.Cache work??

Comment: @Viru...don't know, but I can try

Comment: You may want to look in to a [`System.Web.UI.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx), i've never used it myself by maybe it does what you need.

Comment: Why don't you just set the timer interval to 60 seconds instead of using the counter?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to provide an adequate solution without knowing what you're trying to accomplish with this, but i'll give it a shot.

As Luaan pointed out, controllers are designed to be essentially stateless, so you shouldn't put instance variable on them except for it's external dependencies, since each request creates a new instance of the controller class.

You could store the timer on a static dictionary, indexed by a GUID, and return the GUID on your controller and use it as the cancellation token.

Something like:

```
private static Dictionary<string,Timer> timers = new Dictionary<Guid,Timer>();

public Guid StartCountdown()
{           
    // MAY BE A BAD SOLUTION BECAUSE THE APP POOL MAY RECYCLE
    timer.Interval = _timeIntervalInMilliseconds;
    timer.Elapsed += BroadcastToClients;
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    timers.Add(guid,timer);
    timer.Start();
    return guid;
}

public IHttpActionResult CancelCountdown(Guid cancelationToken)
{
   //If the timer no longer exist or the user supplied a wrong token
   if(!timers.HasKey(cancelationToken)) return; 
   var timer = timers[cancelationToken];
   timer.Stop();
   timer.Dispose();
   timers.Remove(cancelationToken);
}
```

However this won't solve the problem with the AppPool recycling. For a more robust solution, instead of using a timer, you could store the start date and time of each countdown in a more permanent storage (say an SQL database, a NoSQL databse, a redis server or whatever), and have a running thread or global timer, or something like Hangfire, initialized on startup, that constantly checks your countdown storage. If enough time has passed to send a broadcast message you send it, and mark the countdown as finished. If a user wants to cancel the countdown, the controller will simply read the appropiate record, mark it as cancelled, and your running thread can ignore it.

If you go with this approach, you'll need to take into account some considerations:

If the timer interval is set too short you could have a perfomance bottleneck for having to access a permament storage too often. If the interval is too long, the countdown won't be too precise.

To alleviate this problem you could store the countdowns start time in permanent storage, in case the app pool resets and you need to restore them. And also have them stored in memory on a static variable for quicker access.

Please note that if you're working with a server farm instead of a single server, static variables won't be shared across instances.